# How to break at first line on netbeans, java web project

Tags: java, debugging, web, netbeans, break

I'm having issues on my Java web project and I would like to debug it breaking at very first line of the very first java file accessed by the application but I couldn't find this option on netbeans.
I wanted something like this option on PHPStorm.

[image]

Comment: At very first what? First line? Just put a breakpoint.

Comment: What do you mean by the "very first line"? That's not really how frameworks work: you need to decide what you're trying to trace. The entry point varies *wildly* depending on what you're actually doing.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want but...

A global startup -- [ServletContextListener](http://www.deadcoderising.com/execute-code-on-webapp-startup-and-shutdown-using-servletcontextlistener/)

Test specific parts of the app --

-- if a breakpoint in servlet's doGet()/doPost() methods is not early enough, you may put one in the class' static block.

-- you may add a breakpoint into a jsp file.

-- or if the first page accessed is *.html, change its extension to *.jsp, make a <% %> block with some random code and put a breakpoint in there.